# Batch - making a loop to send file to API

Tags: batch-file, lua

I'm currently trying to use the following code to send a file through a compiler online, via an API.

This is my current code:

```
for %%f in (*.lua) do (
    set FROM="C:\Users\Shark\Desktop\test\subdirone\%%f"
    set str="%%f"
    call :Sub %%~nf

    curl.exe -s -X POST -F compile=1 -F debug=0 -F obfuscate=2 -F luasource=@%FROM% http://luac.mtasa.com/ > %str%compiled.lua

    )

:Sub
set str=%str:.lua=%
set str="C:\Users\Shark\Desktop\test\subdirone\%%str%%compiled.lua"
```

I need to include it to this api:
https://luac.mtasa.com/api/ using windows batch.

Any help would be appreciated.

Using luac_mta.exe instead:

```
for %%f in (*.lua) do (
    set FROM="C:\Users\Shark\Desktop\test\subdirone\%%f"
    set str="%%f"
    call :Sub %%~nf

luac_mta.exe -e2 -o %%str%% %%FROM%%
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 goto lp1
   echo "Error"
:lp1

)

    :Sub
    set str=%str:.lua=%
    set str="%%str%%compiled.lua"
```

Comment: Download `luac_mta.exe` and compile locally.

Comment: I'll try, one moment while I audit it to check.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I changed it to be luac_mta.exe now, but I get a syntax error no matter what I try. I'm no pro myself, but I just need this to work despite being ugly. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@cd C:\Users\Shark\Desktop\test\subdirone
@for %%f in (*.lua) do @(
   luac_mta.exe -e2 -o "%%~nf_compiled.lua" "%%f"
   IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
      echo Error in %%f
      pause
   )
)
```